# Need a route called 'tests'

Tags: ember.js

I have a legitimate need to generate a route called 'tests'. The problem is /tests is already being for the built in test runner. Can I reconfigure the test runner to use a different route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

It is defined here:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/e329e3f4c00b78d61e260f054f3d80bb68536f33/server/index.js#L3

It should be possible to write a PR to Ember.js that would allow this.